# Error thrown :Form' does not contain a constructor that takes '1' argument. Any help or correction done to sort this error will be very thankful

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
public void PassValue(string CBA) 
{
   comboBox1.Text = CBA;    
}

public void PassValueA(string CBB)
{
   label14.Text = CBB;
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Form8 Session = new Form8(comboBox1.Text);
   Session.Show();               
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This means that `Form8` is missing this:

```
public Form8(string text) { }
```

If you opened the code-behind for `Form8` I bet you'd see this:

```
public Form8()
{
    // you might even have some code in here
}
```

**BUT**, don't get rid of that one, leave it there. The designer will complain next if you do that. Build the one I gave you, and put your code there. Finally, depending on what the overload does, you might want to base one constructor on another, for example:

```
public Form8() : this("default value") { }
```

That would call the overloaded constructor from the default constructor and send a default value in for the string.

Now, there is a chance you want it to go the other way. No problem, you could do this:

```
public Form8(string text) : this() { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows Form Class by default has Parameterless constructor. But You have define a constructor as follows to pass parameter from other forms or class.

```
public partial class Form8 : Form
{
          public Form8(string info) {

              //do something
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does `Form8` have a constructor that has one parameter? Something like:

```cs
using System.Windows.Forms;

public partial class Form8 : Form
{
  public Form8() // This parameterless constructor is required by the WinForms Designer
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }

  public Form8(string someValue) : this() // Constructor chaining
  {
    // Do something with someValue here
  }
}
```